# Kusto/ Adx: Is it possible to rename a column by a parameter in a function?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

`Custo/ Adx`:

Is it possible to rename a column by a parameter in a function?

For example:

```
function XYZ (column_name: string)
let newColumnName = strcat(column_name, '_starDate')
...
| project-rename newColumnName = oldColumnName
```

I created a function and gave the name as a parameter and tried to use it in `project-rename`.

But `project-rename` does not seem to accept variables.

Comment: Why? What is the use case?

Answer (score 1):

While technically possible, I would not go in that direction.

```
let myfunc = (column_name: string)
{
    let newColumnName = strcat(column_name, '_starDate');
    datatable(c1:int, c2:int, oldColumnName:int, c3:int)
    [
        1, 2, 123, 3
       ,4, 5, 456, 6
    ]
    | extend oldColumnName = bag_pack(newColumnName, oldColumnName)
    | evaluate bag_unpack(oldColumnName)
};
myfunc("MyNewColName")
```

| c1 | c2 | c3 | MyNewColName_starDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 456 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA11Qyw6CMBC8m/gPGy/QZC88DxpPetUfMIaUUgmxFINFJeq/u1CDwvYwye7M7E6VNFC2p0YLWIMrKtWUOtG8lEu4mrrQOZvPnvMZUCmiannf9Jw9UUhBHMHNvw7BSa6G11tupMNWVppxQy9V0hXestAGQfgWK5X9DL%20joENmlQcLXXkIPoLnBwjB0MUQIUIIoxghtt2jhRfIh5E6G6%20gm1OeJxcuzu4ozOQUNpjcuGooSy9rdC%20cMt8U036iu9i1%20962Gy3YB0vvc3NfAQAA)